# Does Duck DB support triggers?

Tags: sql, duckdb

I suspect the answer is no, but I just wanted to check if anyone has a way to implement triggers in DuckDB?

I have a SQLite database that relies heavily on views with INSTEAD OF INSERT/ UPDATE/ DELETE triggers to mask the underlying table structure from applications. Having heard good things about DuckDB I was hoping to try a port, but the lack of triggers (or an alternate mechanism for achieving the same goal) is a show stopper. I've no great desire to reimplement all of the functionality in the various host languages that access the database.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The [documentation](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/overview) of DuckDB (as of Oct'2022) doesn't contain any reference to database triggers.

That said, given the nature of the project -- an *analytical* (OLAP) database, instead of a *transactional* (OLTP) one -- I would say the developers have few incentives to implement this feature, anyway.

Also, [this issue](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/750) on GitHub DuckDB.

Both SQLite and DuckDB are two fantastic tools! But very different beasts. Use the best tool for your job.